# "too quickly" vs "too quickly for me" - what is the difference?

Tags: difference, too

What is the difference between these two sentences?

> He spoke **too quickly to understand**.

> He spoke **too quickly for me to understand**.

I have made a substantial effort to find an explanation in other online sources without finding any explanation that helps me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is the words "for me".

The first means "too quickly for anybody" and the second "too quickly for me (but other people who are better at the language could understand)".